# How to check whether GET is empty?

Tags: php

I am setting some vars from `GET`

```
$start = $_GET['start']; 
$end = $_GET['end'];
```

From which I get:

```
start=1-11-2018&end=30-11-2018
```

And then I am doing:

```
if((!$start) && (!$end)) {
  if (($dateFormat >= $start) && ($dateFormat <= $end)) {
} else {
    echo "no dates";
}
```

And to close it

```
if((!$start) && (!$end)) {
   }
}
```

But this isn't happening

```
if((!$start) && (!$end)) {
```

**UPDATE**

Now this is working but it doesn't go in else if no GET

```
if((!empty($_GET['start'])) && (!empty($_GET['end']))) {
   if (($dateFormat >= $start) && ($dateFormat <= $end)) {
} else {
    echo "No dates";
}
```

Comment: What about [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)?

Comment: @Swellar check updated question

Comment: What is your issue, one of the dates can be empty and the code executes? Maybe `if(!empty($_GET['start']) && !empty($_GET['end'])) {` is what you want.

Comment: What happens when you var_dump $start and $end?

Comment: @Swellar what do you mean about that logic? It just no happening regardless of its logic, meaning it is not getting in

Comment: Well, it is just that the code seems to lack another closing bracket

Comment: " not happening" and "not getting in"  really dont tell us much

Comment: @IdontDownVote check updated question

Comment: @Swellar see updated question

Comment: update is invalid, 3 "{" but only 2 "}"

Comment: @IdontDownVote thanks, updated. Same thing, "echo "no results" is not happening

Comment: @IdontDownVote i think the issue is that I am closing the second if..

Comment: @rob.m It is, your else if is for the nested it, not the outer one.

Comment: What can i do then? I am not sure how to echo that second if and have an else afterwards

Comment: @rob.m Close your nested if (`if (($dateFormat >= $start) && ($dateFormat <= $end)) { }`), or remove it if it's not being used. The code by itself should error because you never closed the `}` on the outer if.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek provided my own answer

Comment: @IdontDownVote i provided my own answer

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is how I resolved it:

```
if((!empty($start)) && (!empty($end))) {
    if (($dateFormat >= $start) && ($dateFormat <= $end)) {
} 
   // here the content which 
  // in case those vars are not empty, 
 // would get filtered by that logic. 

if((empty($start)) && (empty($end))) {
  // Close the condition for second if when not empty
} else {
   echo "No dates";
}
```

Comment: You check `$start` twice, and not `$end`, also have extra `()`s. This looks like my comment.

Comment: @user3783243 yeah was a typo, updated it. Why down votes?

Comment: @user3783243 no, it is not like your comment, since I still had the wrong closing bracket position for that second if

Comment: Not sure about down votes, I didn't vote. You mean because of typos it isn't like my comment? `if(!empty($_GET['start']) && !empty($_GET['end'])) {` looks like exactly what you did.

Comment: @user3783243 nope. If you check the code I had, regardless of this check for empty or not, you can see that I was closing the second if } within the first if, that's why echo "no dates" wasn't happening, I had to close at the bottom

Comment: but the down votes are wrong, because this is the correct solution

Comment: Then I'd guess the DVs are because this is a typo issue.

Comment: @IdontDownVote might you point to me where the wrong syntax is?

Comment: as with the question, count the "{" and the "}"

Answer (score 0):

#### Check via isset()

> if you are calling : http://example.com?start=1-11-2018&end=30-11-2018
>
> ```
> 1. The isset() is checking query string "start"/"end" is having or not. 
> 2. The empty() is checking query string "start"/"end" is empty/blank or not
> ```

```
if( isset($_GET['start']) && isset($_GET['end']) ){ // check the GET method is set or not

    if((!empty($_GET['start'])) && (!empty($_GET['end']))) {
       if (($dateFormat >= $start) && ($dateFormat <= $end)) {
    }
    else {
        echo "Empty dates";
    }
}
else{
    echo "Start / End date query string is missing...";
}
```

Comment: the `} else {` after `if (($dateFormat >= $start) && ($dateFormat <= $end)) {` is checking which `if`?